# Rails migration rename index and foreign_key column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, migration, schema

In my schema.rb,

```
create_table "devices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "uuid"
    t.bigint "device_return_id"
    t.index ["device_return_id"], name: "index_devices_on_device_return_id"
end

create_table "device_returns", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "code"
  t.datetime "returned_at"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_foreign_key "devices", "device_returns", column: "device_return_id"
```

How can I use rails g migration to change all the "device_return" to "exchange" ?

I tired rename_table and rename_index. They didn't change t.index["device_return_id']

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to change the foreign key you can try

```
rails g migration ChangeForeignKeyForDevices
```

then your migration should look like this

```
class ChangeForeignKeyForDevices < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      rename_column :device_returns, :old_column_name, :new_column_name
   end
end
```

then run your migration

```
rails db:migrate
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

rename_column(table_name, column_name, new_column_name): Renames a column but keeps the type and content.

rename_index(table_name, old_name, new_name): Renames an index.

rename_table(old_name, new_name): Renames the table called old_name to new_name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Rails version 6.1.7, and when I use the `rename_column` method like this:

```rb
rename_column :table, :old_column, :new_column
```

It will automatically rename the associated index as well. Therefore, there's no need to rename the index separately.